# Could not write data to text file on Android onTouch event method

Tags: android

I have tried to write some data into a text file inside an Android (target=android-21) onTouch event method using the following code :

```
package com.example.androidwritetxtfile;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textview1;
    String mRootDir;
    File mTemptempDir;
    File mTxtFile;
    PrintWriter pw;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        textview1.setText("AndroidWriteTxtFile");

        mRootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        mTemptempDir = new File(mRootDir + "/temptemp");
        mTxtFile = new File(mTemptempDir, "AndroidWriteTxtFile.txt");

        textview1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                pw.println("Here onTouch()");
                pw.flush();
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            pw = new PrintWriter(mTxtFile, "UTF-8");
            pw.println("This is a testing from AndroidWriteTxtFile");
            pw.println("Here onResume()");
            pw.flush();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if ( pw != null ) {
            pw.close();
        }
    }

}
```

The program compiles OK and runs on my Android device. However, after I check the "AndroidWriteTxtFile.txt" file in my external storage, I find that the "Here onResume()" statement does appear on this file while the "Here onTouch()" statement does NOT.

Does anyone know why I could not write data into a text file while I am inside the Android onTouch event method ?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Do you have the persmission to write in the external storage in your manifest?

Comment: Does logcat show an exception? Have you tried added log statements right before the `println()` calls to confirm that the code is executing at all?

Comment: @Francesco I have written the following statement `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> ` in AndroidManifest.xml. Moreover, the "Here onResume()" statement does appear should indicate that the "AndroidWriteTxtFile.txt" file is opened correctly.